# How to create a relationship property in graphql type definitions using neo4j-graphql library

Tags: neo4j, graphql

Using neo4j-graphql library, from property graph models we could create a graphql type definitions.

For example, for the contrived imdb graph model below:

[image]

We could create graphql type definitions like so:

```
type Movie {
    movieId: ID! 
    title: String!
    actors: [Person] @relationship(type: "ACTOR_IN", direction: IN)
}

type Person {
    personId: ID!
    name: String!
    actorInMovies: [Movie] @relationship(type: "ACTOR_IN", direction: OUT)
}
```

Notice how `@relationship` annotations could be used to establish relationships between different types.

However, neo4j also allows you to create relationship properties as well, as shown in the example below:
[image]

I can't seem to find any neo4j-graphql library document that explains how to achieve this. Please suggest. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

**AS OF 15/06/2021**

Relationship properties are not supported by the Neo4j GraphQL Library. We are working on it right now and you can see the RFC for it here https://github.com/neo4j/graphql/pull/193.

Comment: Are there any work around available as of now? Any suggestion would be really helpful for now!! Thanks.

Comment: Not yet but there is an alpha for relationship properties @ `@neo4j/graphql@next`

Answer (score 0):

Update: [relationship property documentation can be found here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/type-definitions/relationships/#_relationship_properties)